# Can't remove event listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

Can anyone tell why `bt2` event listener is not getting removed in `if` block. As when I remove the event listener in the `p` function, it's getting removed without any error or bug. I am pretty sure there might be any stack or scope problem due to which event listener is not getting removed but I can't figure out what that could be. And I know that event listener is not getting removed as with the succeeding clicks on `bt2` element all the preceding event listeners are also running again, as the same function is running multiple times. Please tell me what's the problem.

Here's the full code:

```
    (function()
    {
        if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
        function init()
        {   var i=0;
            var get=document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click',function() { pro(0);},false);

            function pro(x)
            {   alert('yeah');
                if(!x) x=0
                if(x!=0) //I dont want to remove event listener in the first time , so i want it to function with the next call to pro,in which the value of x is bigger than 0                
{
                    //alert('right'); 
                      document.getElementById('bt2').removeEventListener('click',p,false); //event listener is not getting removed .
                }
                document.getElementById('bt2').innerHTML='this is a button '+x;
                function passTo(y)
                {   
                    pro(y);     
                }
                document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click',p,false);
                function p()
                {   //document.getElementById('bt2').removeEventListener('click',p,false); //here the event listener is getting removed easily
                    passTo(x+1);
                }

            }
        }
    }());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeEventListener` requires that you pass it the **same function**, but your `p` functions are not the same: A new one is created every time `pro` is called. So the one you're trying to remove isn't the one you added, and so it isn't removed.

Removing it *within* `p` works, because within each `p` function, the identifier `p` refers to *that specific `p` function*. So if that one's been added, it will successfully remove itself.

You can prove this to yourself by putting a unique identifier on your function (see comments):

```js
(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

    var functionId = 0; // Something to give us unique IDs

    function init() {
        var i = 0;
        var get = document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click', function() {
            pro(0);
        }, false);

        function pro(x) {
            snippet.log('yeah');
            // We ALWAYS to into the body of this if, the condition
            // is just here for emphasis
            if (!p.id) {
                p.id = ++functionId;
            }
            if (!x) x = 0
            if (x != 0)
            {
                snippet.log("Removing #" + p.id); // <===
                document.getElementById('bt2').removeEventListener('click', p, false);
            }
            document.getElementById('bt2').innerHTML = 'this is a button ' + x;

            function passTo(y) {
                pro(y);
            }
            snippet.log("Adding #" + p.id); // <===
            document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click', p, false);

            function p() { 
                passTo(x + 1);
            }

        }
    }
}());
```

```html
<button id="bt1">bt1</button>
<button id="bt2">bt2</button>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If we run that and click `bt1` once, then repeatedly click `bt2`, we see:

```
yeah
Adding #1
yeah
Removing #2
Adding #2
yeah
Removing #3
Adding #3
yeah
Removing #4
Adding #4
```

Note how each time we're trying to remove a *different* function than we added.

If you want to remove the previous one, you need to remember it elsewhere *(see comments)*:

```js
(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener('load', init, false);

    var functionID = 0;
    var lastp = null; // <===

    function init() {
        var i = 0;
        var get = document.getElementById('bt1').addEventListener('click', function() {
            pro(0);
        }, false);

        function pro(x) {
            snippet.log('yeah');
            if (!p.id) { // Again, always true
                p.id = ++functionID;
            }
            if (!x) x = 0;
            if (lastp) // <===
            {
                snippet.log("Removing #" + lastp.id);
                document.getElementById('bt2').removeEventListener('click', lastp, false);
            }
            document.getElementById('bt2').innerHTML = 'this is a button ' + x;

            function passTo(y) {
                pro(y);
            }
            lastp = p; // <===
            snippet.log("Adding #" + p.id);
            document.getElementById('bt2').addEventListener('click', p, false);

            function p() { 
                passTo(x + 1);
            }

        }
    }
}());
```

```html
<button id="bt1">bt1</button>
<button id="bt2">bt2</button>

<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to fork your `snippet.js`?

Comment: @JonatasWalker: It's on github, so yeah. I just wish SE would get around to fixing Stack Snippets.

Comment: i never thought that they are not the same function , so the reference will be different , well now i made the p function global , and the code is working perfectly , thanks , your advise worked !! i was struck for days on it @T.J.Crowder !!