# Can't remove event listener in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So there is a function that looks like this

```
function eventListener(e) {
    if (!modalRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
      setOpenModal(false);
    }
  }
```

And i add an event listener to listen for event bubbles to the body on startup

```
 useEffect(() => {
    document.body.addEventListener("click", eventListener, true);
    return () => {
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", eventListener, true);
    };
  }, []);
```

And when the component is listening to the bubble state

```
 useDidMountEffect(() => {
    console.log("hello the buble is", buble);
    if (buble) {
      document.body.addEventListener("click", eventListener, true);
    } else {
      console.log("I'm in false mode");
      document.body.removeEventListener("click", eventListener, true);
    }
  }, [buble]);
```

But sadly can't remove it
[prove it's not removing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9WPL.png)

I have read these websites

1. https://www.edureka.co/community/71646/find-event-listeners-node-when-debugging-from-javascript-code
2. [Can't remove all event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48361920/cant-remove-all-event-listeners)

i have also use the arrow function but it didn't work. And also the useDidMountEffect is a custom hook so that the function doesn't run on startup but when i mount it

Comment: Hey there, would you be able to include the code where you declare the buble variable?

Comment: it's basically a state i declared in the same component and can be toggle to true and false to remove the event bubbling

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap your eventListener function to useCallBack with empty array of  dependency.

```
const eventListener = useCallback(function (e) {
  if (!modalRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
    setOpenModal(false);
  }
}, []);
```